# How to add layers and update layer control dynamically : leaflet

Tags: leaflet, google-maps, esri-leaflet, leaflet-draw

**Introduction**

> I am working with the leaflet api, where the user can draw shapes to a
>   map(image)...
>
> Initially the layer control(handling 1 layer) is added for base map
>   using imageoverlay......

**Problem**

> Now, I have added a button of id `newLyer` to page where click event
>   handles the creation of new layer.....i.e user can create new layer
>   and update layer control(which is now handling 2 layers)....
>
> I have used several methods to create the layers and adding to control
>   but failed....

**Adding new layer to layerGroup**

```
var layerGroup = new L.LayerGroup(),
                    imageOverlayUrl = 'aa.jpg',
                    // New imageoverlay added to the layergroup
                    imageOverlay = new L.ImageOverlay(imageOverlayUrl, bounds).addTo(layerGroup),
                    // New featuregroup added to the layergroup
                    featureGroup = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(layerGroup);
```

**LayerControl where i needed to add the control(if i am correct)**

```
        var layerControl = new L.control.layers({
            'Main': layerGroup,
            //here i need to add new layer control
            }, null, { collapsed: false }).addTo(map);
```

**OnClick function with so far static code, this will be executed on click**

```
        $('#newLayer').click(function addNewLayer() {
            // Second layergroup not added to the map yet
            var layerGroupNew = new L.LayerGroup(),
                imageOverlayUrlNew = 'bb.png',
                // New imageoverlay added to the second layergroup
                imageOverlayNew = new L.imageOverlay(imageOverlayUrlNew, bounds).addTo(layerGroup2),
                // New featuregroup added to the second layergroup
                featureGroupNew = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(layerGroupNew);
        });
```

**In Short**

> Initially, i have one layer with its control, now onclick function
>   creates the new layer which will be added to the map but how i can add
>   this layer into layerControl....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are public methods in `L.Control.Layers` control to add base layers and overlays dinamically (see [full reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers)):

- `addBaseLayer(layer, name)` to add new base layer
- `addOverlay(layer, name)` to add new overlay

So, when user clicks on a button, you create new layer and just add it to a control:

```js
$('#newLayer').click(function addNewLayer() {
    //create new layer
    var imageOverlayNew = new L.imageOverlay(imageOverlayUrlNew, bounds);
    //add it to a control
    layerControl.addOverlay(imageOverlayNew, newLayerName);
});
```

And looks like you don't need to use `L.LayerGroup` here...

Comment: Great thanks for help.... i already read the docmentation and solved my problem, although correct answer, +1 for effort